# navigation2 cpp Action with feedback examples

Tags: navigation, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I have reviewed all of the documentation and source code and I am still confuse don how to set up a cpp nav action client and if necessary a server. I have used the top level pub/sub process.  But, I would like more intermediate feedback equivalent to what is provided in the Python3 BasicNavigator class and examples.  Is there an equivalent class for cpp and similar examples.  if there is documentation specific to this that I have missed, please point me to it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396274/navigation2-cpp-action-with-feedback-examples/) by [dennis_bergin](https://answers.ros.org/users/97081/dennis_bergin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Track the Nav To Pose client in the Waypoint Follower as the practical demo of how to work with it https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_waypoint_follower/src/waypoint_follower.cpp#L67. The rviz2 plugin also uses the client as another example. Overall, its the typical Action API but I understand it can be a little daunting for new users, its one of the main reasons I implemented the Waypoint Follower the way I did to be a clear demo.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dennis_bergin](https://answers.ros.org/users/97081/dennis_bergin/) on 2022-02-23**:
Thanks Steve!

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2022-02-23**:
Can you mark this as correct so its off the unanswered questions queue?